# Restarting a service remotely with ssh and sudo errors

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd, systemctl

I am using the following command to try and restart a service

```
ssh username@server "systemctl restart storeapp.service"
```

However I am getting the following error message.

```
Failed to stop storeapp.service: Interactive authentication required.
```

I then tried

```
ssh -t username@server "systemctl restart storeapp.service"
```

This fails because it is not using the correct username to authenticate with it is skipping `username@server` for some other user.  `Authenticating as : otheruser`.  I so have ssh keys set.  How can I over come this?  Or is this a systems admin permissions issue?

If I run `ssh username@server "systemctl status storeapp.service"` that works and I can see the status of my service.

Answer (score 8):

Well, the *easiest* way to fix this would probably be to add:

```
<username> ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl restart storeapp.service
```

To a file in `/etc/sudoers.d`, something like: `/etc/sudoers.d/storeapp` on the target server.

This will allow you to run the command `sudo systemctl restart storeapp.service` without being prompted for a password.

---

**Working example using `ufw`**
*On target host (Ubuntu 18.04):*

```
sudo cat /etc/sudoers.d/ufw 
maulinglawns ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl restart ufw
```

*On your server:*

```
ssh -t maulinglawns@<remote> 'sudo /bin/systemctl restart ufw'
maulinglawns@<remote>'s password: 
Connection to <remote> closed.
echo $?
0
```

As you can see from above, I am prompted **once** (since I don't use a key), but not for the `sudo` command. And the exit status tells us that we succeeded in restarting `ufw` without password. Which I can also verify by checking `/var/log/syslog`.

---

Obviously, this will only work if you have **a)** `root` access to the target server, otherwise **b)** ask the hopefully friendly sysadmin if this is doable and/or acceptable. If **c)** always use `visudo` when editing/creating sudoer files!

> If I run `ssh username@server "systemctl status storeapp.service"` that
>   works and I can see the status of my service.

Yes, `status` does not always require elevated rights.

Comment: Thanks will give this a shot.  Guessing the answer is probably a no.

Comment: this helps me a lot!

Comment: this worked flawlessly. Just a heads up that the new file needs to have 0440 permissions so you should do ```chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/ufw```